# Switch statements - JVM memory allocation, stack overflow

Tags: java

I am taking a Java class in school. We had this assignment to design a class to function as a menu, with several sub menus.

The structure is kinda like this (sort of pseudocode below, just to show structure):

```
public static void mainMenu() {

switch(integer variable){

case 1: submenu1();
break;
case 2: submenu2();
break;
}
}



public static void submenu1() {

switch(integer variable){

case 1: subsubmenu1();
break;
case 2: subsubmenu2();
break;
default: mainMenu(
}
}


public static void subsubmenu1() {

switch(integer variable) {
case 1:  anothersubmenu1()
break;
case 2:  anothersubmenu2();
break;
default: submenu1();
}
}
```

My question is: my teacher said this is wrong, because JVM stores in the memory the path that the program takes from one place to the other if I make it this way, and in the long run this would cause a stack overflow. He didn't quite explained it, he just said that I should surround the whole thing with a while loop using a boolean variable, adding an option to flip that boolean value to exit the while loop, because this way Java wouldn't be storing the path the program was taking from one method to the other.

Again, he didn't explain it with details, and it sounded very confusing the way he was explaining it (I tried to make it as clearly as I could, from what he has given me). I have been looking for the last 3 hours online for anything that resembled what he told me, and I couldn't find anything...so I decided to ask the experts.

Could you guys help me out?

Comment: Please, try to make your example more actual Java syntax. Currently, it doesn’t look like method invocations, but that seems to be what your question is about. In that case, your teacher is right. Recall that a method invocation is something you can return from, to resume the execution in the calling method. Of course, this ability requires storage space, i.e. on the stack.

Comment: I think I got it. But I still would like to learn more about it...

Comment: google "java memory management" or "java memory model", though the stack/heap model is used by most programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the computer executes a method/function call, it has to:

1. Remember what the calling function is doing -- the values of local variables, and where to resume execution when the called function completes;
2. Transfer control to the called function.

When the called function is finished, it:

1. Returns control to the remembered position in the calling function;  There, it
2. Restores the values of local variables, etc.; and
3. Continues processing with the value returned from the called function, if any.

The problem with your system of functions is that they can just keep calling and never return:

mainMenu -> submenu1 -> mainMenu -> subMenu1... etc., etc.

If your functions never return, then it just has to keep remembering more and more stuff each time you make a new call, possibly at some point exceeding the amount of (stack) memory that is available for storing that stuff, resulting in a  stack overflow error.

Some languages implement an optimization called "tail call optimization" that will actually avoid storing those things when calling another function is the *last* thing your function can do.  In this case it's not going to need the values of local variables again, and doesn't need to remember where to resume, because it can resume in *its* calling function, which is already remembered.

In languages like that, your code can actually be OK... but java is not one of those languages.

Comment: Is there a way to make a method return a method call? For example, if I wanted to use the new switch statement with return returning a method call, would that be a viable solution?

Comment: You mean returning a method that the caller would then call?   Yes.  In Java you would return an object that implements an interface, that has a method, that would then be called.  Java makes it easier than it sounds, though -- return a Runnable created with a method reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your teacher is (partly) correct.
The critical part is that you potentially call `mainMenu()` from within `submenu1()` and you call `submenu1()` from within `subsubmenu1()`.
If you call `mainMenu()` everytime you are in `submenu1()` and call `submenu1()` whenever you are in `mainMenu()` your program will crash.

For every function call, the underlying system needs to reserve memory for the function's local variables and such. That's the so-called stackframe. It is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) when you call a function from within itself (directly or indirectly). Recursion needs to return at some point. If it doesn't you get a stackoverflow because the memory runs out.